# Can I un encrypt the password in joomla cookie

Tags: cookies, joomla

Joomla is storing a password inside a local cookie if the user checks the box 'remember me' when you login. 
This code then runs when a succesful login was made.

```
if (!in_array(false, $results, true))
        {
            // Set the remember me cookie if enabled.
            if (isset($options['remember']) && $options['remember'])
            {
                // Create the encryption key, apply extra hardening using the user agent string.
                $privateKey = self::getHash(@$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

                $key = new JCryptKey('simple', $privateKey, $privateKey);
                $crypt = new JCrypt(new JCryptCipherSimple, $key);

                $rcookie = $crypt->encrypt(serialize($credentials));
                $lifetime = time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;

                // Use domain and path set in config for cookie if it exists.
                $cookie_domain = $this->getCfg('cookie_domain', '');
                $cookie_path = $this->getCfg('cookie_path', '/');
                setcookie(self::getHash('JLOGIN_REMEMBER'), $rcookie, $lifetime, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Note $credentials has a ['password'] key value and it does contain the password from the login form.
So if this is encrypted then it must be 2 way for the system to reverse this and populate the password field from the cookie ?

My question is how can I do this..the real clear password is not saved on the users table but an MD5 hashed one. So it must be from this cookie that joomla is able to save the password.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding on **how authentication in Joomla! works**, it goes like this:

- You fill in the user / password
- They get checked by an authentication plugin
- If successfully, a session is created and stored (usually in the database) and also the session id will be stored as a cookie
- As long as the session has not expired, and you open Joomla with the same browser, you are basically automatically authenticated.

**So I really doubt that Joomla! stores any passwords in cookies.** Also passwords are stored encrypted. So Joomla! has no way of knowing what was the original password.

Comment: The password is checked on the server using php (as you say plugin or however) but its all php. The session is created on the database which doesn't hold the password but IF you do elect to be remembered then the password IS stored in a cookie as 2 way encrypted. This is the only time you will get auto authentication.

Answer (score 0):

No it must not be two way: you are simply storing the combination of user + pass ($credentials is an array with the keys 'username' and 'password'), I assume Joomla saves the very same value to the database, and 'remember me' just checks that the stored value (encrypted) is the same as the cookie (also encrypted).

Provided the same sequence is applied the two values will match (as you see there's also  a hash with the website's private key).

Comment: I since found that joomla does save the password value as encrypted (2 way) in a cookie IF you select remember me - then it tries to keep you logged in or rather auto logs you in. This is for scenarios where you own your own laptop etc and we hope that people dont use this on a  cafe machine.

Joomla does store only a hashed password in the db. I could not find any evidence of a password stored in a session.

As for the credentials array which it is yes this is something that they could set to null after login as it exists in memory after it is no longer needed.